# get year, month, day and time form "Tue, 12 Jan 2016 09:40:07 GMT" in Java/Android

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, android-date

I know these type of question asked lot's of time on lot's of website.
Till I not got solution that's why I am putting this question here.

I want year, month, date, date and time from date format

**Tue, 12 Jan 2016 09:40:07 GMT**

I am getting this date format form HttpResponse header and need year, month, date, date from this date format.

Following code I am using but not getting real value:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date date;
try {
date = dateFormat.parse(header.getValue());// here we are getting date in format "Tue, 12 Jan 2016 09:40:07 GMT"
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);

System.out.println("YEAR: " + calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println("MONTH: " + calendar.MONTH);
System.out.println("DATE: " + calendar.DATE);

} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried this also:

1.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

2.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

But all the above code give following result:

```
YEAR: 1
MONTH: 2
DATE: 5
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `calendar.YEAR`, `calendar.MONTH`, and `calendar.DATE` the Calendar class contains static `YEAR, MONTH and DATE` variables so it print value of these variable **i.e 1,2 and 5**.
Instead of it use this:

```
System.out.println("YEAR: " + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("MONTH: " + calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("DATE: " + calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Comment: @Jaiprakesh..thanks...now its working...

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1):

Set timezone to Calendar instance to GMT.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    Date date;
    try {
    date = dateFormat.parse(header.getValue());// here we are getting date in format "Tue, 12 Jan 2016 09:40:07 GMT"
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); // set correct timezone to calendar
    calendar.setTime(date);

    System.out.println("YEAR: " + calendar.YEAR);
    System.out.println("MONTH: " + calendar.MONTH);
    System.out.println("DATE: " + calendar.DATE);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: ...thanks for your reply..
I made the changes : Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
but till not return real value.

Comment: Must be `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))`

Comment: what is your machine's Timezone ? can you post output stack here

Comment: my machine time zone UTC+05:30 ...please find the output in the edited question